# Is it possible to compare two images to verify the exact image is available using TestCaf&#233;?

Tags: node.js, image, testing, icons, testcafe

In our project, there are few icons. Can we able to test those images/icons using TestCafe.

Example code:

```
 <a href="www.fb.com/" class="fa fa-facebook-square"> </a>
```

Expected Result:

- image 1 -> Locally stored
- image 2 -> Available in the website.

And I need to call the local image and compare it with the website image.

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: Sorry @razki, I don't have enough idea about it. And more over, I couldn't able to find any docs related to it. Only thing I found in the internet is js - "imagediff" method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can suggest two ways to compare images on the website.

One way is to [take a screenshot of the DOM element](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/actions/take-screenshot.html#take-a-screenshot-of-a-page-element) with the image and use a third-party library to compare it with the local image. For example, see the [looks-same](https://github.com/gemini-testing/looks-same) library.

Another way is to log a request for the image using [RequestLogger](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html) and compare the response body with the local file using the [Buffer.compare()](https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/met_buffer_compare.asp) method. See the example below illustrating this approach:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import { RequestLogger } from 'testcafe';

const logger = RequestLogger('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/images/landing-page/banner-image.png', {
    logResponseBody:    true
});

fixture `Compare images`
    .page`https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/`;

test
    .requestHooks(logger)
    ('Test', async t => {
        await t.expect(logger.count(record => record.response.statusCode === 200)).eql(1);

        const actualImageBuffer   = logger.requests[0].response.body;
        const expectedImageBuffer = fs.readFileSync('c:\\Tests\\images\\banner-image.png');

        await t.expect(Buffer.compare(actualImageBuff, expectedImageBuff)).eql(0);
    });
```